# MySQL Keep record with most current date

Tags: mysql

I created a table `w_provider_remove` to keep the `Provider_no` and `max(prov_effective_Date)` of the records in `w_providers_load` because I have duplicate providers but some have expired. I later try to join the `w_providers_load` table and the `w_provider_Remove` table and insert the records into the `w_providers_main` table. The problem is I get back to many records because it turns out I have more than one record for the particular provider with the same effective date. How can I limit it so it only inserts one of them? Or maybe there is another way to go about this were I do not need 3 tables to accomplish this task

```
Truncate w_provider_remove;

insert into w_provider_remove
select provider_no as provider_no, max(PROV_DATE_EFFECTIVE) as prov_date_effective
from w_provider_load
group by provider_no;

Truncate w_provider_main;
INSERT INTO w_provider_main
Select l.*
from w_provider_load as l
inner JOIN w_provider_remove as r on l.provider_no = r.provider_no AND l.prov_date_effective = r.prov_date_effective;
```

Comment: Your question is poorly formatted. Impossible for me to understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to limit the rows in the table to one effective date per provider, then create a unique index:

```
create unique index w_provider_load_provider_effectivedate on w_provider_load(provider_no, prov_effective_date);
```

This will generate an error if two records for the same provider have the same effective date in the load.

You can do the same thing for the main table:

```
create unique index w_provider_main_provider_effectivedate on w_provider_main(provider_no, prov_effective_date);
```

Comment: The table that has the duplicates is w_provider_load

Comment: So if I create that index in the table I am moving the providers to (w_provider_main) will it give me the error and no record will be inserted for that provider? or will it insert one provider?

Comment: Whichever table has the index will allow one record to be inserted, but not a second record.  Perhaps you want it on `w_provider_main`.

Comment: I created the index now I get this error I guess cause the w_provider_main has duplicates, it will just give me an error and not insert anything

Comment: INSERT INTO w_provider_main
SELECT L.*
FROM w_provider_load as L
inner JOIN w_provider_remove as R on L.provider_no = R.provider_no AND L.prov_date_effective = R.prov_date_effective;
[Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '100036-2013-01-01' for key 'w_provider_main_prov_date_effective'

Comment: cant i do something like limit count 1 (provider_no) or something to that insert statement

Comment: In MySQL, the easiest thing is probably `insert ignore` (but this ignores all errors).  The more sensible thing to do would be to structure the query as an aggregation, with `group by provider_no, effective_date` to prevent duplicates.